# slide one image off and a new one in using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-animate, gallery, slide

I'm am create a custom sliding gallery using my own animate() method. I have a script which pre-loads the images for the gallery and displays image[0] once the page has finished loading. After a 2 second interval I so far can slide the image element off to the left using the css() method. So far this works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            //pre-load images
            var i = 0;
            var images = new Array();
            images[0] = "images/environments/img0.jpg"
            images[1] = "images/environments/img1.jpg"
            images[2] = "images/environments/img2.jpg"
            images[3] = "images/environments/img3.jpg"

            $("img#cover").attr("src", images[0]);
                $(this).attr("src", images[1]).css("marginLeft","630px");

            $(function () {
                setInterval(function () {

                    $("img#cover").animate({
                        marginLeft: '-980px',
                        opacity: '1'
                    }, 2000);
                }, 2000);
            });

}); //end of document function
```

I now want a way to slide across the gallery(array) and display the next image in the same img element or div tag whichever works best. So after the 2 second interval the "new" one slides in and the "old" one slides off simultaneously.

Im not sure if you can even store two images in the img tag? Is this possible or is it better to slide the div tags off to the left?

HTML:

```
<div id="mainimage"><img id="cover" src="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off having four images and having them masked bi a div using the overflow:hidden attribute.

```
// Your markup
<div id="imgMask" style="overflow:hidden; height:200px; width:200px;">
    <div id="inner" style="position:relative; left:0;">
        <img src="images/environments/img0.jpg" />
        <img src="images/environments/img1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/environments/img2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/environments/img3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

// Your js
function slideLeft(){
    $('#inner').animate({
        left: -200px;
    },2000, function(){
        $('#inner img').eq(0).remove().appendTo('#inner');
        $('#inner').css({
            'left',0
        });
    });
}
```

This way you are only sliding one parent element instead of multiple images.  Hope it helps - the above code is untested but assumes you have an image height and width of 200px, and of course the styles are better off in your stylesheet than being inline like this.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense I will try it out. I even thought about 'stitching' the images all in line in PS and then using overflow:hidden technique stupid yes but a last resort.

Comment: what does .eq() do? And append() do?

Comment: .eq(a) selects a single element from the collection at index a (so in this case, the first image).  And appedTo('#inner') takes the element and puts it inside '#inner' at the end.  So basically that line removes the first image and puts it at the end, so that your images will continue looping indefinitely.

Comment: ok thanks so much for explaining. I have tried your code and it worked beautifully. there was an error in the css syntax but once i fixed it it worked a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to add whole img tags to your div. Like so:

```
<div id="mainimage">
   <img id="cover1" src="scr1.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
   <img id="cover2" src="scr2.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
   <img id="cover3" src="scr3.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

And the fade them in and out as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can slide out the old image, then once the animation is complete you change the img src and slide it in from the other side (1-change src, 2-set display: hidden, 3-position the image on the other side, 4-set display: block, 5-slide in animation).

The slide out and slide in won't be simultaneous but you can get a nice effect.

If you need a simultaneous slide in/slide out I'd go as well for two img tags.

Hope this idea helps